# How Add customer in Magento via program

Tags: customer

I am converting my old website into magento. How i add my customer into Magento via program

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which e-commerce platform were you previously using? Which version of Magento are you migrating to? Imagine this was somebody else's question and you read it. Would you be able to answer with the little bit of information you provided us? Read this for reference: http://tinyurl.com/stack-checklist

Answer (score 1):

this is sample code

**customer.php**

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once 'app/Mage.php'; // please include full path of Mage.php
Mage::app('default');


$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$password = 'test1234';
$email = 'mylogin@test.com';
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
$customer->loadByEmail($email);
if(!$customer->getId()) {
    $groups = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/group_collection')->getData();
    $groupID = '3';

    $customer->setData( 'group_id', $groupID );
    $customer->setEmail($email);
    $customer->setFirstname('test');
    $customer->setLastname('testing');
    $customer->setPassword($password);

    $customer->setConfirmation(null);
    $customer->save();

    echo $customer->getId();
}
?>
```

now you can get 
customer.php location via look this line in code

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
```

Now this is sample code you can take required fiels as per your requirement. and you can take data via excel file also for this just modify this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can import them by using Import/Export function in admin panel (System->Import/Export). You have to create .csv file with customers.

Here is another thread which can guide you how to do it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773763/import-customers-to-magento-via-csv